# Very Strange issue by testing an app on an iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, xcode4.4

I've a very stange issue testing my application build with xcode.
I start the XCODE IDE and connect my iPad wich is provisioned for testing.
Then I press the Play button or use the shortcut to deploy the App onto my device.

But if i want to test the App a 2nd time (normally I press CMD+R) nothing happens.
Just one time i got an error (**timed out waiting for app to launch**).

On the Simulator everything works fine.

I've tried to fully recreate the project without any success.

What the f*** is the reason?

Im running XCODE 4.4

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: what happens if you run the app directly from the iPad, no Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the issue but it's also very very strange.
I'm working with a webview in my app and images are placed there.
Now the problem appears if I use jpg images there (Interlaced).
If I use the same image with an alternative format (as png) and its filesize is up to times bigger everything works OK.

It's sort of weird.

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons for this. Most of the time there are some process stuck on your iPad. Just restart your ipad, clean your project and relaunch. This should take care of it. To prevent further problems like this. Make sure you stop the app on xCode before launching a new build while debugging (ie: during stepping through breakpoints). And try not to launch the same app too fast twice, that can also bring problems.

If restarting does not work, then that means you screwed up something on your project. Try looking around what you did. As a last resort, build a new project and transfer the important file there.

Comment: I've already recreated the project and also removed all of my code (problems continue also if I just runt the corpus  of that app)